# AWS S3 multipart upload does not load in parallel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My uploads were taking about 30s to upload a 20MB file so I switched to multipart upload and it is still taking about 30s to upload a 20MB file.

I have a feeling it has to do with this function:

```
  function createMultipartUpload(s3, multiPartParams, buffer) {
    partNum = 0;
    startTime = new Date();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.byteLength / partSize);

    s3.createMultipartUpload(multiPartParams, function(mpErr, multipart){
      if (mpErr) { console.log('Error!', mpErr); return; }
      console.log("Got upload ID", multipart.UploadId);

      // Grab each partSize chunk and upload it as a part
      for (var rangeStart = 0; rangeStart < buffer.byteLength; rangeStart += partSize) {
        (function(rangeStart) {
          console.log("PART ");
          console.log(rangeStart);
          partNum++;
          var end = Math.min(rangeStart + partSize, buffer.byteLength),
              partParams = {
                Body: buffer.slice(rangeStart, end),
                Bucket: multiPartParams.Bucket,
                Key: multiPartParams.Key,
                PartNumber: String(partNum),
                UploadId: multipart.UploadId
              };

          // Send a single part
          console.log('Uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber, ', Range start:', rangeStart);
          uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams).then(function() {
            console.log('1');
          });
          var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
          console.log('This part took', delta, 'seconds');
          if(rangeStart > buffer.byteLength - partSize) {
            deferred.resolve();
          }
        }(rangeStart));
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

When it gets down to uploadPart it does not do it asynchronously:

[image]

If you add up those seconds you get around 30s.  If it was in parallel it should really take about 7.5s.

I'm not sure why this is happening since the function is called inside of a closure which is looped so it should be asynchronous right?

Here is the code in full:

```
var startTime;
  var partNum = 0;
  var partSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // Minimum 5MB per chunk (except the last part) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.html
  var numPartsLeft = 0
  var maxUploadTries = 3;
  var multipartMap = {
      Parts: []
  };

  function completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    s3.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("An error occurred while completing the multipart upload");
        console.log(err);
        deferred.reject();
      } else {
        var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
        console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds');
        console.log('Final upload data:', data);
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum) {
    console.log("UPLOADING PART...");
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var tryNum = tryNum || 1;
    s3.uploadPart(partParams, function(multiErr, mData) {
      if (multiErr){
        console.log('multiErr, upload part error:', multiErr);
        if (tryNum < maxUploadTries) {
          console.log('Retrying upload of part: #', partParams.PartNumber)
          return uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum + 1);
        } else {
          console.log('Failed uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber)
        }
        return;
      }
      multipartMap.Parts[this.request.params.PartNumber - 1] = {
        ETag: mData.ETag,
        PartNumber: Number(this.request.params.PartNumber)
      };
      console.log("Completed part", this.request.params.PartNumber);
      console.log('mData', mData);
      if (--numPartsLeft > 0) deferred.resolve(); // complete only when all parts uploaded

      var doneParams = {
        Bucket: partParams.Bucket,
        Key: partParams.Key,
        MultipartUpload: multipartMap,
        UploadId: multipart.UploadId
      };

      console.log("Completing upload...");
      completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams).then(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  // Multipart
  function createMultipartUpload(s3, multiPartParams, buffer) {
    partNum = 0;
    startTime = new Date();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.byteLength / partSize);

    s3.createMultipartUpload(multiPartParams, function(mpErr, multipart){
      if (mpErr) { console.log('Error!', mpErr); return; }
      console.log("Got upload ID", multipart.UploadId);

      // Grab each partSize chunk and upload it as a part
      for (var rangeStart = 0; rangeStart < buffer.byteLength; rangeStart += partSize) {
        (function(rangeStart) {
          console.log("PART ");
          console.log(rangeStart);
          partNum++;
          var end = Math.min(rangeStart + partSize, buffer.byteLength),
              partParams = {
                Body: buffer.slice(rangeStart, end),
                Bucket: multiPartParams.Bucket,
                Key: multiPartParams.Key,
                PartNumber: String(partNum),
                UploadId: multipart.UploadId
              };

          // Send a single part
          console.log('Uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber, ', Range start:', rangeStart);
          uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams).then(function() {
            console.log('1');
          });
          var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
          console.log('This part took', delta, 'seconds');
          if(rangeStart > buffer.byteLength - partSize) {
            deferred.resolve();
          }
        }(rangeStart));
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Code comes from this guy: https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803

Comment: Are you sure you have no outbound speed limit?

Comment: A speed limit?  What is that?  How do I check for that?

Comment: Is it a speed thing?  I thought it was a synchronous thing

Comment: Check it on speed test pages, http://beta.speedtest.net/ .  Looks like your upload speed is limited.